# Laravel - AWS Beanstalk - Storage symlink not working (403 error)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk to deploy my laravel application. Everything is working fine except for my images as I need to create a symbolic link with storage to access it publicly.

*P.S. Works fine on my local*

**My .ebextensions file is as follows -**

```
commands:
  composer_update:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root

container_commands:
  01-install_dependencies:
    command: "php /usr/bin/composer.phar install"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  02_storage_sym_link:
    command: "php artisan storage:link"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
    leader_only: true
```

**Below is the log from my ec2 instance to confirm that the command worked just fine and the link was created successfully.**

```
[2019-04-21T15:47:16.899Z] INFO  [21538] - [Application update symlink alt2@208/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Synchro/Test for Command 02_storage_sym_link] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-21T15:47:16.903Z] INFO  [21538] - [Application update symlink alt2@208/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Synchro/Test for Command 02_storage_sym_link] : Completed activity. Result:

  Completed successfully.
[2019-04-21T15:47:16.903Z] INFO  [21538] - [Application update symlink alt2@208/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Synchro/Command 02_storage_sym_link] : Starting activity...
[2019-04-21T15:47:17.014Z] INFO  [21538] - [Application update symlink alt2@208/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Synchro/Command 02_storage_sym_link] : Completed activity. Result:
  The [public/storage] directory has been linked.
```

**The error I am getting is as follows which makes the images unavailable for public access.**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /storage/blog/images/8Yhb4OZJQIKwlMGaGE803niTxyjfzNSVTj2BiPaP.gif on this server.
```

Any help guiding me to the right path is appreciated. Cheers!

---

**EDIT 1 :**

```
container_commands:
  01-install_dependencies:
    command: "php /usr/bin/composer.phar install"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  02_storage_sym_link:
    command: "ln -s storage/app/public public/storage"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  03_give_ec2_user_perm_1:
    command: "sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/app/current"
  03_give_ec2_user_perm_2:
    command: "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/app/current"
```

Tried creating the symlink manually plus gave permission to the ec2-user. **But still no luck :(**

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the uploaded image?

Comment: Yes, I am. My end goal is to create a symbolic link with the storage folder so that I can access those images in my view publically.

Comment: check my answer, that may give you some idea, I had faced it before sometime, I solved it by referring documentation, I have added the link too.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it seems to be an issue related with the server somehow as it's working just fine on my local. I've added a comment to your post. *P.S. My command snippet and log does show I'm running the artisan command successfully to create the symbolic link*

Comment: Are you able to access any other file in public directory successfully ?

Comment: Yes, the application is working just fine. It's the first line of my post. :)

Comment: Can you check what is the permission for image folder and also can you post the code you have written to display your image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192176/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-thebrownkid).

Comment: As there is no response still, I would like to know, how you are retrieving these images?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Your concern is appreciated but you are completely on the wrong path. I would suggest you go through the whole question again. Btw here is our continued convo which I didn't get a reply for -> [screenshot_chat](http://prntscr.com/ng6b9u)

Comment: if the image is public, then you may use your public dir directly rather then using storage. by changing your filesystem.php setting.

Comment: @thebrownkid In beanstalk, you can't use to store the files better to use S3 along with a project for storage and images support.

Comment: @PranavanSp **Thank you for suggesting an alternative workaround. It does the work!!** Rather than working around the webapp user permissions on beanstalk, I used S3 for storage purposes. It does the work so I can skip the symlink issue for now.
*Still curious though as to how we can fix the issue related with the symlink permissions on beanstalk. Please do share if you have any experience around it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting down an **alternate option** which does the job for people who are/might have a similar issue -

**Use S3 for file storage in your Laravel application.**

To make it happen -

1. Create a public S3 bucket.
2. Create an IAM user which has full access to
       S3 bucket. *(With the access key, the application will have
       permissions to read and write in the S3 bucket.)*
3. Update the config file `filesystems.php` to use the S3 bucket. *(This config handles the storage config of the application.)*

Refer the [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) for more info.

*Thanks to @PranavanSp for his suggestion.*

Answer (score 2):

Container commands are run as root, that is why when you tried to run it as the ec2-user you couldn't. The ec2-user is not in the root user group.

Then when you create symlinks, try to do it in the actual app directory(current):

```
container_commands:
  01-install_dependencies:
    command: "php /usr/bin/composer.phar install"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  02_storage_sym_link:
    command: "ln -s storage/app/public public/storage"
    cwd: "/var/app/current"
```

Or try to link directly as so:

```
container_commands:
  01-install_dependencies:
    command: "php /usr/bin/composer.phar install"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  02_storage_sym_link:
    command: "ln -s /var/app/ondeck/storage/app/public  /var/app/current/public/storage"
```

EBS Files can be annoying to get right at first but worth it in the end. If this still doesn't work, maybe the user(appache I assume) that runs the server does not have access to that folder. To just quickly verify this just do a:

```
sudo chmod -R 755  /var/app/ondeck/storage/app/public
```

Comment: Exactly, I believe the same as well but can't find a way to override the permissions. Btw your help is appreciated and what I've figured after banging my head around this is that when we deploy an application it is first done to `/var/app/ondeck` and after which all our container commands are run on it. Only after everything is ready, the files are moved to `/var/app/current`. So, basically running commands on current won't help at this stage at all as that folder contains the previous version of the app.

Comment: Hmm okay. Give post deployment hooks a shot, it is basically a bash script that gets run after container commands and after the app is copied over. I found this https://deliciousbrains.com/scaling-laravel-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-part-3-setting-elastic-beanstalk/ which might be of help, they did one specifically for Laravel and AWS EB

Comment: But first try the permissions using the container commands, found an example for Laravel and EB: https://github.com/TheDMSGroup/laravel-eb/blob/master/.ebextensions/40_laravel.config But this might be a bit old

Comment: Thank you @DR., will give both a try later and will update you. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, the only reason I am saying to try the permissions first is that the error 403, means permissions, so the server user might not be able to read from the file it is trying to. If the 403 goes away and you get a 404, then it probably means the symlink is not working. That is how I would go about solving this.

Comment: Any luck in solving the problem yet?

Comment: Nope still struggling with it boss.

Comment: any update on that?